# Aggregation, Sorting, Filtering and Pagination with Microservices having their own database

Tags: pagination, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0, api-gateway

**Approach and Requirement:**
We have a microservices architecture developed in ASP.Net Core with Sql Server database, where each microservice has its own SQL database and we are not allowed to do cross microservice communication for aggregating data and sending back from microservices to api gateway and further back to UI (browser).

Our browser has a data grid which needs data to be displayed after aggregating it from different microservices e.g. one data grid has to show a customer name, address, booking ref. number, country name, hotel name, hotel address, hotel cost and some other more details.

There is also a functionality in above data grid to sort above grid data based on each column in it; filtering the grid is also a requirement based on different column values. In addition, we also need to do pagination in this same grid with a page size of 10 records.

Currently, as per my knowledge the data aggregation has to happen in API Gateway layer and on top of it the sorting, filtering and pagination functionality has to be applied.

We are using EF Core 2.0 as the data ORM to send back the data to microservices and further up the response.

**Question 1**:

> which layer (UI, API Gateway, Microservices) should do this sorting,
>   filtering and pagination functionality so as to have optimal
>   performance and better user experience?

**Question 2**:

> Is it possible that all parameters such as sort order, sort col name,
>   page size, page number, filter col name, filter col value all should
>   always be sent to the microservice api from API Gateway layer and
>   successfully achieve all the functionality without any latency and
>   optimal performance in read operations?

**Question 3:**

> Is it a good pattern that we instead of above options, create a
>   coarse-grained microservice which does the aggregation, sorting,
>   filtering and pagination of data instead of the API Gateway layer
>   doing Aggregation (currently API Gateway is only doing aggregation in other microservices)?

Comment: This sounds like the microservices haven't been set up correctly. You should have one service/database per subdomain of your application. For example, you shouldn't have a CarService and an EngineService, and a TireService, and then query all three to get information about one car. Engines and Tires are part of the Car domain, with Car being the aggregate root. In other words, if you're having to aggregate data from multiple services just to get one complete entity, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks I agree, but as per my app's business domains, we can't combine Customer, Booking and Hotel domains in same microservice boundedcontext. Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: That's not true at all. There are definitely scenarios where you need to join + aggregate data from different micro-services such as front-end applications and data indexing operations. For example, Facebook app might show friend messages and news posts in the newsfeed. Are you saying that you should keep friend messages and news posts together in 1 service to avoid aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the most elegant and performant answer here will be to create a caching layer accessed at the API gateway layer - see this discussion of the possibilities: http://rafaborrego.co.uk/how-to-do-pagination-across-domains-in-microservices-architectures/

There's a fundamental issue where, without a caching layer, for every request you'll need to gather essentially all data from the constituent microservices to enable Pagination, Sorting, and Filtering (PSF).

It doesn't make sense to send all that data to the UI layer as that puts a lot of memory pressure on the user, and the microservices themselves at best only have the ability to implement filtering.

Answer (score 0):

1) That depends on the nature of your data. For example, if you have a core service with the data that you are paginating and sorting then that service should do it. One example, is you want to display a user's hotel bookings in sorted order. So you might have 3 services to host the bookings, users and hotels info. In this case, the core service doing the pagination is the bookings service. You retrieve the bookings data then supplement each booking with hotel + user info.

2) latency will always be there. The whole idea of micro-service would introduce latency because you are adding more network interactions. But that is the cost for abstraction and fast iterations. However these things can be resolved with caches and db improvements. Besides, if you are paginating results the data should be limited anyways so performance should not be a concern

3) yes, definitely a possibility, it's actually quite a common pattern